# How to receive zip file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, flask

Alright, here's the problem.

I'm trying to send a ZIP file from a Python Flask server to a NodeJS backend so I can download it from the frontend webpage. Unfortunately, when the response to the request reaches the backend, it triggers a "HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT" code error.

This is the Python code

```py
zipfolder = zipfile.ZipFile(filename,"w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_STORED)
zipfolder.write(file)
zipfolder.write(file2)
zipfolder.close()
return sendfile(filename,mimetype="zip",download_name=zfile,as_attachment="True")
```

This is the code at the backend of the page:

```js
async function data(vars){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    form = new FormData()
    //insert data in form
    axios.post(url,form,{headers:form.getHeaders(),maxBodyLength:Infinity}).then((resp)=>{
      var zip = new JSZip()
      zip.loadAsync(resp.data,{base64:true}).then((z)=>{
        resolve(z)
      })
    }).catch(err=>{
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

With this configuration, I'm getting the error `Error: Invalid base64 input, bad content length.`

If I replace `{base64:true}` with `{base64:false}`, I get the error `Error: Corrupted zip: missing 45305 bytes.`

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the code you're actually running, since `result` is not defined.

Comment: @AKX True. I forgot to put resp.data instead of result.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`, so Axios is trying to decode your zip data to a string and corrupting it as it goes. Beside that, you're leaking variables (`form` etc.) to global, and you're misusing promises, so all in all, things might simplify to something like:

```
async function data(vars) {
  const url = '...';
  const form = new FormData();
  // ... put things in the form...
  const resp = await axios.post(url, form, {
    headers: form.getHeaders(),
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  });
  const zip = new JSZip();
  return zip.loadAsync(resp.data);
}
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't give an error message now. However, the ZIP file I get in the end is empty. I guess there must be something I'm missing in the rest of the file. I'll try a different way to get what I want. Thanks, anyway.